# WCF as BLL (Middle Tier) and Security techniques

Tags: wcf, security, model-view-controller

So bear with me, i am new at MVC and WCF. I already have a set of services (WCF) that exposes my BLL and I am trying to consume those from my MVC.net web application but i am unsure on how to perform security operations here.

These are my app requirements:

- Be able to consume WCF services using different credentials for every user on the web application
- My BLL (WCF) needs to know what consumer is calling it (right now I only have the MVC app but i am planning to add iOS and Andriod calls to it, so later on i will add REST services to the WCF endpoints) Is there any design pattern for this out there? (or should i just use the soap header to include the caller ID? should i use some sort of caller secret or something?)
- I need a security mechanism like Tokens or something so I dont have to pass the username and password on every call of the service method (WCF)

What i have so far:

- WCF uses a certificate and  and   with a custom username validator.
- I have manually coded proxies using the contract interfaces instead of generated proxies: But I hate the fact that i have to validate username and password every time a call is made to a WCF service. How in heaven can i use Tokens here? like to know if a given token sent on the soap header is valid or not yet expired? i have searched a lot and no tutorial/code/example is clear enough for me to actually start coding that ;(
- I am trying to cache the ChannelFactory but should I? i mean, i will need to cache a channer factory per logged in user per contract ;( is that ok? what can i do here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this blog post can help: http://webservices20.blogspot.ca/2009/01/stateful-security-context-tokens-in-wcf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you cache the ChannelFactory per user per contract?

It depends. There are a couple of considerations. Instantiating a channel factory could take up to 70ms. If you are doing this repeatedly, you will see a noticeable performance hit if you are not caching the ChannelFactory and instantiating one (or more) each time a user makes a http request to your MVC app that results in controller actions calling web services. This would indicate that caching the channelFactory would be beneficial for speed.

On the other hand, depending on the number of users you have, if you are caching a lot of channel factories (in a static dictionary for example), you are going to start to use a non-trivial amount of memory - this may become an issue for you.

You have to decide if the cost of instantiating channel factories on the fly (and correctly closing / aborting them and their contained channels) is too high a price vs increasing memory utilisation in the application pool hosting your MVC app.

Either way, I strongly advise to profile your app before you deploy to production.